# SQL Server - Listar Alterações de uma só coluna

Tags: sql, query, select, group-by, distinct

Tenho essa gama de dados - Data, valor

[Dados Gerais](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdGWI.png)

E preciso selecionar somente as linhas que obtiveram valores alterados. (Linha 1, 2, 5, 6, 10, 15)
Tentei utilizar o group by

```
SELECT 
[InFlowRate]
, max(baseDateTime) as DataAlteracao
, max(idScales) as Balanca
FROM [aetISA01Estatisticas].[dbo].[tblStatScalesData_S30]
group by InFlowRate
```

e também o `DISTINCT`, mas não retorna todos os registros alterados

Como posso analisar a linha anterior e verificar se houve alteração para realizar um select que retorne essas linhas demarcadas?

[Dados filtrados que quero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiGxZ.png)

Comment: de uma conferida na função [Lag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score -1):

Não testei, mas talvez funcione.

```
Select * FROM (
SELECT 
[InFlowRate]
, max(baseDateTime) as DataAlteracao
, max(idScales) as Balanca
FROM [aetISA01Estatisticas].[dbo].[tblStatScalesData_S30]
order by baseDateTime

) as tabela group by [InFlowRate]
```